# Custom Page in Tridion is some times opening in new Tab Instead of Pop Up?

Tags: 2011

I have created an Item selector application which shows the directory structure on the aspx page. On click of any file in this structure will set the file path in tridion's component field. I am attaching the image for component strucuture.

[image]

Here I have a season component with episode as a multi-valued embedded field. Episode schema is also having an embedded field to select media links which has a field for custom url which opens up the aspx page.

For first episode when I click the custom page link it work fine and open up in pop up.
The issue which I am facing is that when I add second episode and click the custom url link it get opened in new tab instead of pop up. I have also found that in IE8 it is working fine on my machine but not on IE8 on other machine.

In chrome and firefox it is not working.

Comment: Few information needed:
1) Have you created your own Item Selector or have used the one already available as the Community Extension - If it is former one, then can you verify for possible bugs in it.
2) IE8 on other machine and Chrome/Firfox issue - is it having all the right settings for opening a pop-up and executing a JS?

Comment: 1) I have created my own Item Selector. 2) Yes settings are correct. Popup is not opening when this scenario occurs

Comment: The logic of Custom URLs opening is simple, At first it tries to open a popup, and then as a fallback it opens a New Tab. In your scenario, for some reason something went wrong in second episode. Can you look at if you have any javascrip errors?

Comment: Very long shot: It's a multiple-value field. The next field is loaded/added asynch. Could it be that the JavaScript event to open the custom page isn't added to the newly added field? (Because it's loaded async?) Not sure (yet) on how to test this...

Comment: There was no JavaScript error. And this issue was faced by others as well when I tried to discuss with other people

Comment: The behavior of Custom URL opening is the same as the one which opens History dialog for instance, if you have this dialog working correct (and browser independent), then the issue is in your code somewhere. If this dialog does not work correct then the issue is in Tridion and should be reported.

Comment: "I have also found that in IE8 it is working fine on my machine but not on IE8 on other machine." - can you confirm both instances of IE don't have any active plugins - you need to find a consistent test base/replication pattern first.

Are you also sure that the second instance of the field/popup is not conflicting with the first (e.g. unique ID/path etc.)?

Comment: I have found that for IE it is working well on a number of machines. So that is sure this is not a defect for IE.

Comment: If it is working fine on one machine and not on others, then I would say it is not an issue of the browser or SDL Tridion, but an issue in the configuration of the browsers on the machines where it is not working?

Comment: +1 to Bart's point and also UIBeardcore's simple check (try History or other pop-ups). Maybe confirm the IE settings, which include a "when a pop-up is encountered" option to open tabs, new windows, or to let IE decide.

Comment: @AlokBhatt - did the solution below work? did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It has been somewhat of a mystery to me how the JavaScript `window.open()` command behaves. You will find several explanations on the internet that you should use things like:

```js
window.open("www.yoururl.com", "_blank");
```

or

```
window.open("www.yoururl.com", "_newtab");
```

But in some cases your browser will simply refuse to open in a new tab and do it in a popup window. When working on my [View in Staging and Live UI extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/view_in_staging_live.aspx), I finally figured out how this behavior works, with thanks to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript#13158856);

> `window.open()` will not open in new tab if it is not happening on actual click event.
>
> If the `window.open()` method is called on an actual click event, it should always open in a new tab, unless you set window size properties. This will of course only work if the user has appropriate settings in his browser.

So as a developer you most of the time have control over how you call this method, and thus how you want the window to be opened. In my mentioned extension, I was initially calling `window.open()` in a event handler method, so `window.open()` was called asynchronously and thus no matter what I used, it always opened in a popup window, rather than a tab. To solve this I have used the following code:

```js
// open window on actual click event with about:blank page
var tab = window.open("", "some name");

// event handler
var onItemLoaded = function whatever$_execute$_onItemLoaded() {
    $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", onItemLoaded);

    // some code to determine the url from the loaded item
    var url = siteUrl + item.path;

    // open url in tab and set focus
    tab.location.href = url;
    tab.focus();
};

// load item asynchronously
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", onItemLoaded);
item.load(item.isLoaded(true), $const.OpenMode.VIEW);
```

Now that is the explanation why sometimes when you want to open a window in a tab, it can just open as a popup window. But on IE I have also seen a different behavior which I can only explain as a defect in IE. As the OP has mentioned, in most cases the window is opened as expected (in a popup window). So this code must use the following call (or something like it):

```
window.open("www.theurl.com", "window name", "width=500,height=600");
```

It should never, in any case, open in a new tab, as it is called with the [`specs` argument](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). But I have seen this behavior before (opening in a popup window once and in a tab later), and only on older IE browsers. So the only thing I can conclude from that, is that this is a defect in IE...