# How to return value to the multilevel embedded schema field from Custom URL?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, custom-url

I'd like to use Custom URL to populate embedded schema field. First level and Second level embedded schemas made as repeatable. 
First Level : **NameValueSet**
Second Level : **NameValuePair**.
I am able to pass value to the first child(namevalue) but not for the  further childs within the same embedded schema.Whenever I try to add values to the next childs the popup is opening in new tab instead of in a new popup and `window.dialogArguments` is returning NULL.
If I am repeating the first embedded schema I am able to pass the value to component.
PFB the source of the component:

```
    <contentschema xmlns="uuid:4cd36b65">
    <NameValueSet>
        <NameValuePair>
            <namevalue>Authenticated - Yes</namevalue>
        </NameValuePair>
                <NameValuePair>
            <namevalue>**UNABLE TO ADD HERE**</namevalue>
        </NameValuePair>
    </NameValueSet>
    <NameValueSet>
        <NameValuePair>
            <namevalue>Subproduct - GP</namevalue>
        </NameValuePair>
    </NameValueSet>
    <NameValueSet>
        <NameValuePair>
            <namevalue>Subproduct - MRKT</namevalue>
        </NameValuePair>
    </NameValueSet> 
</contentschema>
```

Please find below how my schema look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the dialogArguments. Have you tried accessing to the field builder directly?

Check this out.

```
var componentWindow = window.opener.window;
var componentView = componentWindow.$display.getView();
var fieldBuilder = componentView.properties.controls.fieldBuilder;

fieldBuilder.getField("FieldPath").setValues(["value"]);
```

You can access fields by path and set values from a popup.

Answer (score 3):

Would you like to refer this question - 
[Custom Page in Tridion is some times opening in new Tab Instead of Pop Up?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/custom-page-in-tridion-is-some-times-opening-in-new-tab-instead-of-pop-up)

This is still unanswered but have few comments which you can follow and see if this resolve your issue.

I am kind of pretty sure that this is something related to the browser behaviour.

Try changing your browser - something like IE and see if it works.